# Scala view bounds that work with subtypes?

Tags: scala

Is there anything in Scala like a view bound but which can match subtypes?

Since views in Scala do not chain, I currently have the following:

```
implicit def pimpIterable[A, I[_]](x: I[A])(implicit f: I[A] => Iterable[A]) =
  new { def mylength = x.size }
```

to let me write:

```
Array(1,2,3).mylength
Seq(1,2,3).mylength
```

The above form seems necessary since if I try to simplify my function signature with something like:

```
implicit def pimpIterable[A, I <% Iterable[A]](x: I) =
  new { def mylength = x.size }
```

then the implicit conversion won't work for Arrays since there is no direct view from Array to Iterable (only to a subclass of Iterable, which the first form is able to find).

This also forces all other short-hands to be written out in long form as well.  What could have been:

```
implicit def pimpIterable[A: Scalar, I <% Iterable[A]](x: I) = ...
```

must now be written as:

```
implicit def pimpIterable[A, I[_]](x: I[A])(implicit f: I[A] => Iterable[A], m: Scalar[A]) = ...
```

Is there a Better Way?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with the view bound signature. First, `Iterable` doesn't have `length`, only `size`. Next, `I` is not a type cosntructor. So, fixing both, the signature is:

```
implicit def pimpIterable[A, I <% Iterable[A]](x: I) = new { def mylength = x.size }
```

This is proper. If you parameterize `I`, it will exclude types such as `BitSet` and `String`.

Comment: Hi, Daniel.  Thanks for pointing out the errors - that's what I get for trying to distill out a minimal example for illustration without actually trying to compile it.  However, this still doesn't really answer the question about view bounds and subtypes - your version still doesn't work with Array.

Comment: @Yang Well, you can write `Iterable[_]` and it will work, but I assume you need `A` for something? This particular example doesn't use it.

Comment: Yeah, mylength is just a silly example. I do use A (e.g. `def mymap[B](f: A => B) = ...`).